# Postgres HStore usage

Tags: database, postgresql, hstore

Its probably easy to figure out by doing a benchmark, but i wanted to post this to see if any one has gone though this debate before.

Here is a simplified version of my problem -

I have an entity

```
 CREATE TABLE entity (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   some_field INTEGER NOT NULL
 );
```

I want to store price info for this entity for each country.

So I have two ways to go about it.

1. I create another table that links back to entity table with a foreign key

   ```
   CREATE TABLE entity_price (
      entity_id INTEGER, //Foreign key to entity table
      price DECIMAL(8,2),
     currency char(3)
   );
   ```
2. OR I can enhance the entity table and add an HSTORE

   ```
   CREATE TABLE entity (
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      some_field INTEGER,
      price_info HSTORE
   );
   ```

In my case, every time I read my entity, I need to read the price info. For every row in the entity table there is pricing data. I can see benefits/drawbacks of both approaches 1 & 2

Approach 1

- Having to query another table every time i have to read an entity is basically additional non-contiguous disk IO that postgres has to do ( i will be doing join queries ).

Approach 2

- Using Hstore co-locate the pricing info into a single record. But then Hstore is slower for read queries.

In my case I will be using Hstore for mapping

COUNTRY CODE -> {price, currency}

I will be writing some tests to compare performance of both approaches. But I also wanted to check if anyone has any opinion on the same.

Comment: I read about TOAST tables, which makes me inclined to use hstore - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html

Comment: Consider the impact on updates too - updating a GiST index over a hstore is slower, and when any field is changed the whole row with the hstore must be rewritten.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Thanks for the comment. The Postgres doc says ---

"During an UPDATE operation, values of unchanged fields are normally preserved as-is; so an UPDATE of a row with out-of-line values incurs no TOAST costs if none of the out-of-line values change."
---
So i think unless the value in HSTORE column is changing, the update would not require HSTORE data to be re-written.

Comment: Correct, but if you change *any* value in the hstore, the whole row and the hstore must be rewritten.